# chat program fork seem not to receive messages

Tags: c, linux, fork

I am trying to write a simple chat program. The idea is basically straightforward, two files containing messages and this  seem to work ok. Problem is in fork system calls. File on recipient's side is not being displayed. ChildProcess is either terminated too early, or  there are some other issues I do not recognize.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char MyName[256], RecName[256]; 
int  Over=0;

int  SendMsg (char* name)
{
FILE *file;
char BufText[1000]; 
int  n=0;
char sign;
    fflush(stdin);              
    printf("To %s: ", name);
    n=0;
    do {
        sign=getchar();      
        BufText[n++]=sign;
        if(n>=998) break;    
    }while(sign!='\n');      
    
              
   BufText[n]=0;                
   if(BufText[0]!='\n') {       
        file = fopen(name,"a"); 
                                    
        if(file!=NULL) {            
                                    
            fwrite(BufText, sizeof(char), strlen(BufText), file); 
            fflush(file);  
            fclose(file);
        }
        else return -1; 
    }
    else {
       return 0;   
                   
    }
    return 1;
}

int  ReceiveMsg(char* name)
{
FILE *file;
char sign;
int result =0;
    file=fopen(MyName,"r"); 
    if(file) {
        if(fread(&sign,sizeof(char),1,file)==1)  { 
            result=1;                               
            printf("From %s: ", name);                  
            printf("%c",sign);                         
            while(fread(&sign,sizeof(char),1,file)==1) {  
                printf("%c",sign);
            }
            file = freopen(name,"w",file);    
        }
        fclose(file);                     
        return result;
    }
    return result;
}

void  ChildProcess(void)
{
    int receive;
    do {
        receive = ReceiveMsg(MyName);
        sleep(1);      
    }while (receive == 1); 
}

void  ParentProcess(void)
{
    int result;
    do {
        result = SendMsg (RecName);
    }while(result != 0);
    
    
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 pid_t  pid;
    if(argc>1) strcpy(MyName, argv[1]);
    else {
        printf("Your name ?: ");
        scanf("%s",MyName);
    }
    if(argc>2) strcpy(RecName, argv[2]);
    else {
        printf("Recipient ?: ");
        scanf("%s",RecName);
    }

     pid = fork();
     if (pid == 0) 
          ChildProcess();
     else 
          ParentProcess(); 
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: And did you do any debugging at all? Such as run your program in a debugger and/or add more debug print statements to trace what the program is doing? If so, what did you find? [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not be contributing to your specific problem, but...
The usage of [fwrite()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fwrite.htm) in your code should pass the full length of the buffer being passed, but is passing one byte short...

Try changing this:

```
fwrite(BufText, sizeof(char), strlen(BufText), file);
```

to either

```
fwrite(BufText, sizeof(char), sizeof(BufText), file);
```

or

```
fwrite(BufText, sizeof(char), strlen(BufText) + 1, file);
```